# How to use wasmer in iOS?

Tags: webassembly

Wasmer is a cross platform webassembly runtime. I want to run wsam on IOS platform. There is no tutorial in the official document, and I can't find the demo on the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

wasm3 runs on a wide range of architectures (x86, x86_64, ARM, RISC-V, PowerPC, MIPS, Xtensa, ARC32, ...) and platforms:

```
Linux, Windows, OS X, FreeBSD, Android, iOS
OpenWrt, Yocto, Buildroot (routers, modems, etc.)
Raspberry Pi, Orange Pi and other SBCs
MCUs: Arduino, ESP8266, ESP32, Particle, ... see full list
Browsers. Yes, using WebAssembly itself!
wasm3 can execute wasm3 (self-hosting)
```

https://github.com/wasm3/wasm3

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Wasmer does not support iOS</s>. It will likely not be possible to run WASM on iOS without a big runtime penalty or precompiling, since Apple does not allow the usage of Just-in-Time compilers.
This was discussed in this Wasmer issue: https://github.com/wasmerio/wasmer/issues/1832
**(Please check my update below)**

As Bitmaya pointed out Wasm3 would be an option since it uses an interpreter to run WebAssembly and therefor is not effected by the JIT ban.
Other projects like wasmi should also work.

I am not a iOS developer so I can't give you exact details on how to include them in an iOS app, but I hope this answers at least parts of your question.

---

EDIT:

I missed an update on that issue.
It seems like they added iOS support for one of the backends (Pull request: https://github.com/wasmerio/wasmer/pull/2535).

You can check the example here: https://github.com/wasmerio/wasmer/blob/81c090c6ea79f7b5705b4cbb07311169799fd091/examples/platform_ios_headless.rs

However it should be noted that the example does not allow you to dynamically run any WebAssembly on iOS it just creates a shared library that you can use in your app.